# UI problems when changing the screen-resolution

Tags: qt, screen-resolution

I'm new to Qt and am having problem when I change the resolution of my application. I'm working with embedded application, using DirectFB.

My UI was designed for 1280x720, where it works fine! At 1920x1080, the UI is small but still good. The major problem is when the resolution is changed to 720x576, the UI is really big and I can't seem to resize the objects inside a widget or call a function to adapt the UI.

These additional resolutions options came after the start the project, so I didn't know about it.

Any ideas on how to solve this? I'm thinking about designing a new UI, just for 720x576, but this doesn't sound great, right?

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the UI at 720x576 to visualize the problem?

Comment: It's a little hard because my application is cross compiled then it's running in a set-top box. In fact i can get a screenshot but i need set up some things for that. I'll set up and to post here...

Comment: OK, i just need ask my manager project about to show our UI. Anyway i think than wouldn't have problems. =)

Comment: If that's a problem, you can create a small dummy application with fewer widgets that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The solution depends upon what you want to do in the low resolution. Do you want it to look the same, but without the larger images or do you want to display a different design? It may not be practical to use the same design for a lower resolution.

The first thing to do is to connect to the QApplication::desktop() resized event to detect that a screen resolution change has occurred. At this point you could either forward the event to all your widgets to resize and use different images, resize the images they have, or display different forms that you create for different screen sizes.

Depending upon the design of the UI, a new design for that resolution may indeed be the best option, but we'd need to see the design to give an opinion on that.

Comment: Exactly @Merlin069, i would like to look the same but without the larger images. About to connect resized event to the QApplication::desktop() is not so simple because when user changes the resolution, i need reboot my set-top box and set up DirectFB with new resolution.

I thought about to resize images, fonts, etc, always to instance a new widget in my UI verifying my resolution, but i'm searching a easier choice. Sounds hard to work with many resolutions...

Comment: Sorry, I missed that DirectFB is an embedded device that you're using. If you want the images to be the same size proportionally to the screen resolution then the only options I think you have is to either reduce the image sizes on the fly, after detecting the lower screen resolution, or have a separate set of images to load, which would be much quicker than the first option. If you're likely to have a lot of other resolutions, choosing hi-res images and downsizing will be the least amount of work for you.

Comment: Yes @Merlin069, i think that is really the better solution. I have a file containing the user preferences including the current resolution, so i'm testing what resolution is being used and if is 576 i resize the icons, widget and fonts. Is not a beautiful solution but works fine... Thank you a lot for your answers.